# How to persist the hover template if you click whilst hovering?

Tags: onclick, plotly, plotly.js

I’m trying to get it so that if I’m hovering over a marker and the hover template is shown, that I can click to have the template stay where it is when I mouse away. Then you could click again to hide it. When a hover template is persisted the rest of the plot continues to show hover templates as they did before.

The idea is that people can highlight a few markers of interest before downloading an image.

I've posted this on the plotly forum too but I didn't get any responses: https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-persist-the-hover-template-if-you-click-whilst-hovering/73361

I’ve seen some pointers about creating annotations on click. But it seems awkward to me to try to re-create the hover using an annotation?

This example seemed to do what I wanted: [Hover events in JavaScript](https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-events/#combined-click-and-hover-events)

I think the idea is to add a new trace when you click, but I don’t see how the new trace is set up to always show the hover text? Also, I found the sheer volume of data points and traces slowed down the tab to the point that the browser complained about the script and offered to kill it for me. I think this is the approach I want? But I couldn’t get it to work with my set up.

Am I on the right track? Is there something else I should be trying? Can anyone help me understand how the example works?

Thanks!

Comment: i believe the function `pathBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){ .. }` is where the persisting of the hovertemplate is being added in the javascript. as for the sheer volume of data points, that's unfortunately a different issue where too much data will overwhelm the renderer (see [plotly's own benchmarks](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/~plotly.js/133.embed))